# Sending JSON request with parameters from obj-c

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, json

I've been trying out lots of tutorials and SO question to find a way to make the below code work in obj-c. Its a json response from the server, but nothing i've tried works. How should I make the below code in obj-c?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$.ajax({

    url: "http://myjsonurl.com",
    data: { employerID: "1", startDate: "2013-09-13", endDate: "2013-09-15" },
    success: function(data) { console.log(data); }
});
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the JSON server in your domain? If not, you'll need to use JSONP and the server will need to support it.

Comment: its in my domain, yeah. @Andy My problem isn't not getting an answer, its actually sending the request, simple as that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this response page to be purely JSON like so,

{ "employerID": 1, "startDate": "2013-09-13", "endDate": "2013-09-15" }

Make sure to put quotes around those keys unless they are variables.

You can use a third-party tool (linked to one below) to call this url and get the response as data, then convert the data to a NSJSONSerialization object in the completion block.

https://github.com/andrewapperley/AFFNetworking

Answer (score 0):

This is not only json response HTML script also came ,
Inform to your web-service person  clear the HTML script give as array , dictionary format result

Comment: what? I can't understand what you're trying to say

Comment: this is not a json response.This is just html page.

Comment: html page in json format or whatever then, server guy says it is